# Splitting lines from a file into parts

Tags: string, perl, file, split, lines

Hopefully this is the correct way to ask for assistance. I've been set an assignment that has been split into three parts and its the first part I have having trouble with. I have to Load a file into a List which I have done, its the part where I need to split each line of the file into 3
Currently my programming looks like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub LocationCount ($$$$) {
  my ($FileName, $DKm, $Lat, $Lon) = @_;
  my ($Index, $Species, $Latitude, $Longitude);
  my @List;

  open(INF, "<", $FileName) or die("Cannot open Mammal.txt\n");
  @List = <INF>;
  @List = split("\t", @List);

  for ($Index = 0 ; $Index < @List ; $Index++) {
    print("Species Name: $List[0]\n");
    print("Latitude: $List[1]\n");
    print("Longitude: $List[2]\n");
  }
}
```

What returns when I run the full program is:

```
Use of uninitialized value $List[1] in concatenation (.) or string at Assignment.pl line 19, <INF> line 125000.
Use of uninitialized value $List[2] in concatenation (.) or string at Assignment.pl line 20, <INF> line 125000.
Species Name: 125000
Latitude:
Longitude:
```

Basically it should look like:

```
Species Name: Myotis nattereri
Latitude: 54.07663633
Longitude: -1.006446707

Species Name: Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato
Latitude: 56.12259134
Longitude: -4.49369336
```

(x125,000)

The txt file given to me is sorted like this, with the species name followed by the tab for latitude then another tab for longitude:

```
Myotis nattereri 54.07663633 -1.006446707 
Pipistrellus pipistrellus sensu lato 56.12259134 -4.49369336 
Myotis daubentonii 52.24773003 -1.084432324
```

Each species is on its own line

What I'm asking is basically, why is it returning the number of lines in the file and not spliting every line into three parts? While fiddling around with it I've managed to get it to repeat:

```
Species Name: Myotis nattereri
Latitude: 54.07663633
Longitude: -1.006446707
```

125,000 times which isn't what I want to happen.
Thank you for any assistance, and I'm really sorry if I've phrased this wrong or its formatting wrong. I've looked for other answers and tried out some answers from people with similar problems but they just aren't working for me.

Comment: You must *never* use subroutine prototypes in Perl (like `sub LocationCount ($$$$)`). They are very different from prototypes in other languages and do *not* do what you think they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
@List = split("\t", @List);
```

The `split` operator expects a single string as its second parameter and applies scalar context to it. Passing an array here will result in an attempt to split a string containing ing the *number of elements* in the array.

For instance

```
perl -E "@data = qw/ a b c d /; say for split /\t/, @data"
```

produces

```
4
```

There is a number of other problems

- You *must never* use subroutine prototypes in Perl (like `sub LocationCount ($$$$)`). They are very different from prototypes in other languages and do not do what you think they do
- Perl won't enforce it, but programmers familiar with the language will thank you for using lower case letter and underscores for local identifiers. Capitals are reserved for global names, like package names
- You should use lexical file handles in preference to global ones (`$inf` instead of `INF`). Well done with choosing the three-parameter form of `open`
- The first parameter to `split` is a *regular expression*. If you pass a simple string then it will still be compiled as a regular expression, so it is best to use slashes as the delimiter, like `split /\t/, $line`
- Perl has better options than the C-style `for` list. If you're not interested in the index into an array then you can write just `for (@array) { ... }`

Your code should look something like this

```
use warnings;
use strict;

sub location_count {

  my ($filename, $dkm, $lat, $long) = @_;

  open my $inf, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};
  my @list = <$inf>;

  for my $line (@list) {
    my @fields = split /\t/, $line;
    printf "Species Name: %s\n", $fields[0];
    printf "Latitude:     %s\n", $fields[1];
    printf "Longitude:    %s\n", $fields[2];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
I'm still a beginner in perl, so I'm not sure what %s\n means. And how does printf work? I've never seen it in that context before.

Comment: @Arkturaz: You are very welcome. I have added a lot to my answer that you should read.

Comment: Excellent answer. Personally, I prefer splitting into variables instead of using array indices, but that's just me: `my ($species, $latitude, $longitude) = split /\t/, $line;
printf "Species Name: %s\n", $species;
...`

Comment: Thank you for the additional advice, its quite clear I'm still very much a beginner haha! I'm still confused as to what printf does, I've only ever used print as "print ("Species Name: $List[0]\n");". I understand that %s is used to insert a string, when playing around with the code to understand it I still cannot get it to work when I put it to how I normally use it.

Comment: @Arkturaz When you're not sure what a built-in function does, `perldoc -f function`, e.g. `perldoc -f printf`. The online version is [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I would normally agree, but that in this case the OP *declared* appropriate variables but then went on to *use* array elements. Unless the problem is trivial I like to use `my @fields = split` and then use an array slice to extract the useful fields, which in this case would look like `my ($species, $lat, $long) = @fields[0, 1, 2]`. You will have to imagine a much bigger row to see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Do Line by line processsing by changing:

```
@List = <INF>;
@List = split ("\t", @List);
```

to

```
while (<INF>) {
    chomp;
    my ($species, $latitude, $longitude) = split "\t";
    ....
```

Comment: Good advice in general, but the OP said their assignment is to "load a file into a list" (I assume they mean array).

Answer (score 0):

Declare this at the top:

```
use diagnostics;
```

I prefer `diagnostics` helpful tool when you're first learning Perl's warnings.

You will need to remove the newline char from the line. When you use `chomp` an array, it will remove a newline from the end of every element in the array.

```
open(INF,"<",$FileName) or die ("Cannot open Mammal.txt\n");
@List = <INF>;
chomp(@List);         ### Add this before spliting
@List = split ("\t", @List);
```

Run the script again.

Also, **if you are really sure about what you're doing** then you can use 
`no warnings 'uninitialized';` at the top and see what the output comes.

Answer (score 0):

To process the infile, use

```
while (my $line = <INF>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my @List = split /\t/, $line;

    print("Species Name: $List[0]\n");
    print("Latitude: $List[1]\n");
    print("Longitude: $List[2]\n\n"); 
}
```

instead of

```
@List = <INF>;
@List = split ("\t", @List);

for($Index=0;$Index<@List;$Index++)
{
    print("Species Name: $List[0]\n");
    print("Latitude: $List[1]\n");
    print("Longitude: $List[2]\n"); 
}
```